# App development: Always subclass, always load from NIBs - caveats?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, generics

This is Cocoa Touch (et al), iPhone, XCode only.

After completing my first commercial iPhone app, I'm struggling a bit to find a way to start and expand an app from scratch which gives the most linear development (i.e., the least scrapping, re-write or re-organization of code, classes and resources) as app specs change and I learn more (mostly about what Cocoa Touch and other classes and components are designed to be capable of and the limitation of their customization).

So. File, New Project. Blank window based app? Create the controllers I need, with .xib if necessary, so I can localize them and do changes requested by the customer in IB? And then always subclass each class except those extremely unlikely to be customized? (I mean framework classes such as UIButton, CLLocation etc here.)

The question is a generic 'approach' type question, so I'll be happy to listen to handy dev practices you've found paid off. Do you have any tips for which 're-usable components' you've found have become very useful in subsequent projects?

Clients often describe programs in terms of 'first, this screen appears, and then you can click this button and on the new screen you can select... (and so on)' terms. Are there any good guides to go from there to vital early-stage app construction choices, i.e. 'functions-features-visuals description to open-ended-app-architecture'?

For example, in my app I went from NavBar, to Toolbar with items, to Toolbar with two custom subviews in order to accommodate the functions-features-visuals description. Maybe you have also done such a thing and have some advice to offer?

I'm also looking for open-ended approaches to sharing large ("loaded data") objects, or even simple booleans, between controllers and invoking methods in another controller, specifically starting processes such as animation and loading (example: trigger a load from a URL in the second tab viewcontroller after making sure an animation has been started in the first tab viewcontroller), as these two features apply to the app architecture building approach you advocate.

Any handy pointers appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Lots of good questions here. I would hold off on writing apps for real clients until you get them answered.

Comment: Hehe, it's already too late for that. And I believe the best way to get experience is to get elbow-deep. Or ask experienced guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this up as there's no single correct answer and was more suitable for the other forum, had I known it existed when I asked :)

If you want to know the method I ended up with, it's basically this:

1. Window-based blank app
2. Navigation Controller controls all, whether I need to or not (hide when not used)
3. Tab Bar Controller if necessary
4. Connect everything <-- unhelpful, I know.
5. Set up and check autorotation, it might get added to some view later.
6. Add one viewcontroller with xib for each view, you never know when they want an extra button somewhere. It's easier to copy code than make the max ultra superdynamic adjustable tableviewcontroller that does all list-navigation, etc.
7. Re-use a viewcontroller only when just the content differs in it, such as a detail viewcontroller.
8. Minimize code in each viewcontroller by writing functions and methods and shove them in a shared .m
9. Everything that's shared ends up in the App delegate, except subclassed stuff.
10. Modal viewcontrollers are always dynamically created and never have an xib.